# DataTables warning: table id=bootstrap-data-table - Invalid JSON response - DataTables JS Plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables

I'm getting the following error using  WebMethod in a Web Form application:

> DataTables warning: table id=bootstrap-data-table - Invalid JSON
>   response. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

This happens on the button click in my Jquery code when trying to display my data in a DataTables table. Can anyone advise what I'm missing?

**Jquery:**

```
document.getElementById("openReqMenuButton").onclick = function () {
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('#bootstrap-data-table').DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    'searching': true,
                    'sort': true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Pages/Requisitions.aspx/GetOpenRequisitionData",
                        "type": "POST"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { 'data': 'ReqId' },
                        { 'data': 'RequisitionTitle' },
                        { 'data': 'City' },
                        { 'data': 'Country', },
                        { 'data': 'DateCreated' },
                    ]
                });
            });
        };
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="bootstrap-data-table" class="display" style="width:100%">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="bootstrap-data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="2">ReqId</th>
          <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="bootstrap-data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="2">Requisition Title</th>
          <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="bootstrap-data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="2">City</th>
          <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="bootstrap-data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="2">Country</th>
          <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="bootstrap-data-table" rowspan="1" colspan="2">Date Created</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

Comment: try debugging your return data first and then try putting sortable false in your columns and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a tbody tag. I think it's required for DataTables:

```
<div>
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Identifier</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="TableBody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```